# JSCS FIX : Expected end of node list but "CommentBlock" found

Tags: javascript, node.js, jscs

I got a new mac recently cloned the repo and installed all the packages.  When I run my linter it gives me below error.

Expected end of node list but "CommentBlock" found at

```
./stack/surface/features/stack/ui/kit.js :
     1 |// ## packages
--------^
     2 |const {
     3 |  React,
```

I have tried searching but nothing came up as a valid solution on the interweb's. If you have any idea or ran into a problem like this please can you share your golden knowledge. Anything would be appreciated.

this is my JSCS  config
**.jscsrc**

```
{
  "preset": "node-style-guide",
  "maxErrors": 10,
  "maximumLineLength": {
    "value": 205,
    "allExcept": [
      "urlComments"
    ]
  },
  "disallowSpacesInFunction": null,
  "disallowKeywordsOnNewLine": null,
  "requireCapitalizedComments": null,
  "requireCamelCaseOrUpperCaseIdentifiers": {
    "ignoreProperties": true
  },
  "requireCurlyBraces": [
    "if",
    "else",
    "for",
    "while",
    "do",
    "try",
    "catch",
    "default"
  ],
  "requireSpacesInFunctionDeclaration": {
    "beforeOpeningRoundBrace": true,
    "beforeOpeningCurlyBrace": true
  },
  "fileExtensions": [
    ".js",
    ".jsx"
  ],
  "excludeFiles": [
    "build/**",
    "cargo/**",
    ".idea/**",
    ".nu/**",
    "node_modules/**",
    ".git/**",
    "db/**",
    "brand/**",
    "_build/**",
    "_cargo/**",
    "_cargo/*/**",
    "bridge/**"
  ]
}
```